# CountIF by date and year

Tags: excel, date, countif

In excel, I have a table that contains dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy.  I am trying to gather some stats on this table, more specifically how many there are from a month number that is stored in another cell and the current year. So for example if the value in the other cell was 1 and the current year was 2015 I would want to return the number of dates from January 2015.  Would this be possible by a count if statement? Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With A1 being the cell containing the Month number, try:

```
=COUNTIFS(TableDateColumn,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),A1,1),TableDateColumn,"<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),A1+1,1))
```